# Growing memory footprint from use of UIImages

Tags: objective-c, swift, uitableview, memory, uiimage

My app utilises tableviews that all have associated UIImages. 
I show my UIImages in the app using:

```
cell.foodImage.image = UIImage(named: foodImageArray[indexPath.row] + ".jpg")
```

I know in objective c something such as

```
UIImage initWithContentsOfFile
```

Could be used in order to keep the memory footprint low.
Is there something like this I can use in swift?

Comment: That `[UIImage initWithContentsOfFile:]` is somehow faster than `UIImage(named:)` is a false premise. If there is a memory problem, you'll have to provide more details.

Comment: Are you actually running out of memory? If so, the first technique to look at is to resize the jpeg image to the size of the `foodImage` image view. It is a huge waste of memory to make your image view display a big image at a small size.

Answer (score 0):

`UIImage(named:)` caches once loaded image and keeps it in run-time until app quits or 'out of memory' notification from system, on which cache somehow cleaned up automatically.

Thus it is better to use this constructor only for small images, which are either always visible in UI or used often.

For other cases (probably your table view case is here) it is better to use `UIImage(contentsOfFile:)` constructor with implemented some in-app cache logic to keep it for some workflow only but clean when go out it (other mode, scenario, etc. including force cleaning for 'out of memory' notifications)